# How to know a browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome) is installed or not by java code?

Tags: java

I want to launch a URL by multiple browsers. But before launching, I want to check if the browser is installed or not. How can we do so with Java code? Thanks!

Comment: First, I would check to see what ways are available to do this "normally" under your target system. You may find there's a registry key you can look up on windows, but that's going to require a native library to access

Comment: @MadProgrammer : tks Mad but you can tell me what 's name library ?

Comment: I use TeamDev's JNIWrapper and WinPack libraries, but you could also look for JNA